# What requirements does Outlook have on RSS feeds?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016, rss

I've scrubbed some data and have converted it into an RSS feed file.  (Or I think I did.) Then I tried to go to Outlook to add the RSS feed to my mailbox, and I received a vague error message:

> Outlook cannot process the RSS content from C:\... . The link may not point to a valid RSS source.

I am modeling my file off the first page of [RSS web pages on www.w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_rss.asp).

I validated a redacted feed file to https://validator.w3.org/feed/.  I found, according to it, that I wasn't using RFC-822 date-times, I wasn't giving GUIDs that were unique enough.  Corrected.  But not enough to satiate Outlooks rules.

I'm still figuring out if there is something I can change with regards to restrictions MS Outlook might have on using local files?  Encodings?. I'm not well versed on dealing with encodings, but I'm learning.

I have failed to Google this answer well.  I would appreciate a clue via a search term, if you could offer one.

Much Thanks to all so far.

Comment: Thinking about this a different way, what's your use case? What are you turning into an RSS feed that's on your local C:\ drive?

Comment: We have a webmaster who publishes a list of documents on a HTML 2.0 webpage, with publish date, title, description, link to PDF.  I've asked him to convert this list to something RSS friendly, but the boss... so I've done it for my self and my group, at least that was the plan until I hit this barrier.

Comment: thanks for the edits

Comment: Found a helpful website... I'll revisit this tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

Answering mine own question.  As a quick web hosting solution I posted my RSS feed on a Git Hub repository.  The feed worked, after not working from the local drive.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing. By the way, would you mind marking your own reply as the answer so that other users who have the similar issue could benefit from your thread?

Comment: I dislike it when question/topics are not marked as "answered" when they obviously should be.  In this case I didn't not answer my question, but merely solved the problem, and this answer is one possible solution of how to trick Outlook into revealing a feature and "show" that it does not support another.  I much better like to get a link to a Microsoft site that tell it as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook seems only support RSS Feed links: [Subscribe to an RSS Feed](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/subscribe-to-an-rss-feed-73c6e717-7815-4594-98e5-81fa369e951c). About how to create an RSS Feed, maybe you could check this article: [How to Create an RSS Feed](https://www.cloudwards.net/how-to-set-up-an-rss-feed/).

Comment: caveat: links contains ads